# Given concatenated substrings prepended with the number of characters in each, separating them

Tags: java, string

I'm parsing the body of an HTTP request containing separate strings concatenated with the number of characters of each string preceding it. Like this -

```
"12Dogdogdogdog3cat1a4Goat"
```

I'm trying to get back the original strings.

There's no guarantee that the strings don't contain numbers, so something like this would be acceptable -

```
"3Cat4Go1t"
```

What I need to do is read the first number, Read that number of characters, then read the next number, that number of characters, and so on, so forth, for any arbitrary length string.

What would be the idiomatic Java (Java 8 is fine) way of doing this? I've managed to write an unwieldy series of nested loops, iterating character by character, but they fail for more than 10 characters in a sub-string.

Said nested loops -

```
    ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();

    System.out.println(concatMessages);

    int i = 0;
    while (i < concatMessages.length())
    {
        int numCharsMsg = Character.getNumericValue(concatMessages.charAt(i));

        String msg = "";
        for (int j = i + 1; j < i + numCharsMsg + 1; j++)
            msg += concatMessages.charAt(j);
        messages.add(msg);

        i += numCharsMsg + 1;
    }
```

Thank you for your help!

(I'd also appreciate better approaches to concatenating strings for reliable later separation.)

Comment: What happens if a substring has leading digits? How do you distinguish whether `"1210aaaaaaaaaa"` represents the length-12 string "10aaaaaaaaaa" or the length-1 string "2" and the length-10 string "aaaaaaaaaa"?

Comment: It's helpful to share what you have tried.

Comment: That is a huge flaw in my approach. An addition, then - I need to store multiple strings in a one-string HTTP request body and later separate them out accurately. What might be a better approach than what I've come up with?

Comment: From your text and your comments, it is unclear if you are both generating and processing such headers or only processing them and they cannot be changed.

Comment: Both generating and processing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split your data with a special separator, like | or tab, then use the String.split using this special separator to get all items.

Comment: That is not a solution to the OP problem. It is like someone having issues with divisions and telling them to use additions instead.

Comment: This was the first approach that came to mind for me (and is honestly better than what I've come up with since), but I'm not sure what could be a good separator. Do you know of a separator that would certainly not be in an HTTP request?

Comment: I agree with you @SJuan76, but check the user2357112 comment, what if your text is "123A14"? Your full content will be something like 6123A143XYZ. How do you parse using this using this algorithm? 
Daniel Moore, select a separator that you know it will be not used. Using the | as separator, the example above will be 123A14|XYZ. If this does not work, try a bigger separator, like ##@##. 123A14##@##XYZ.